Computed the same Milnor and Tjurina number for $f$, yet $f$ is not quasihomogeneous.
Let $f: \mathbb{C}^{n}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a germ of analytic function defining an isolated hypersurface singularity at the origin. Then the Milnor number equals the Tjurina number if and only if $f$ is quasihomogeneous (K. Saito 1971)
Consider the polynomial $f=y^2-x^2-x^3$ in $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$. Both the Milnor and Tjurina number is 1, but this polynomial is not quasihomogeneous. Why is this the case?

The singularity is analytically isomorphic to $$(x-y)(x+y) =0$$
because $1+x$ is locally a unit and has a square root.
I didn't study the statement by Saito, but I guess there has to be something along the lines "there exists a quasi homogeneous representative".

Was there anyone more familiar with this expand on this answer? Specifically the guess part of the answer at the end.

@Snared Skimming Saito's paper I didn't find any mention of Milnor or Tjurina numbers, but for example in Satz 4.1 his formulation is more or less (translated by me): If the ideal generated by the partial derivatives of $f$ contains $f$, then there is a coordinate transformation which transforms $f$ into a quasihomogeneous polynomial. That's the kind of result I would expect for your case as well. (Does the premise of Satz 4.1 hold if the Tyurina number equals the Milnor number?)
